# WebClient.DownloadString("https://....") Crashes. No Exceptions

Tags: vb.net, https, webclient

I'm at a loss here. I have created an API for a website of mine (If it's of any value, this is being locally hosted for easier development). I am *trying* to pass it some info via a simple GET request, but I'm running into a big problem.

```
Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim ServerResponse As String = wc.DownloadString(New Uri(entireRequest))
MsgBox("This will NEVER be run")
```

The above code is being run in a separate thread. The problem is that when the `DownloadString` line is called, no other code afterwards is ever run. I have tried setting breakpoints after that line and none are hit.

A `Try...Catch` block does nothing. I have tried catching `Net.WebExceptions` and System.Exceptions. Nothing's ever caught. My breakpoint on `End Try` is never hit..

I have noticed that this will only happen if `entireRequest` is an https connection. This problem doesn't happen if it's not encrypted.

Adding the following in order to ignore the self-signed cert does nothing:

```
Public Class clsSSL
    Public Shared Function AcceptAllCertifications(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

**Thanks in advance! I've done a lot of searching and you're my last hope!**

Comment: Why do you use multithreading instead of `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync`?

Comment: I have other code that I need to run in a separate thread along with the code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved thanks to this thread:** [Requesting html over https with c# Webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064505/requesting-html-over-https-with-c-sharp-webclient)

I just needed to add the following:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

I'm still confused as to why I wasn't being presented with any exceptions. Any answers on that?

Comment: I could only guess as to the reasoning and if thought about logically it was literally just stuck there. Similar to an infinite loop but with a single line instead of multiple ones. It possibly could have just kept trying to process that line and just failed and crash because of it.

Comment: You're probably correct. DownloadString is a blocking method, so it was probably just hung indefinitely. It's surprising that there is no built-in timeout or failsafe.