# How can I use WebClient.DownloadString from a secure URL (https)?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

The code I'm using is

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();                    
string xmlResult = webClient.DownloadString("https://kat.cr/usearch/ubuntu/?rss=1");
```

I'm a bit confused as the URL seems to tunnel through to a secondary page
kastatic.com:443 and then kat.cr:443 (if I'm understanding Fiddler correctly).

The server certificate seems to be fine so adding the following code does nothing helpful

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    };
```

I've also tried setting the useragent headers on the webClient object in case I need to identify as a browser or something but I don't think I'm on the right track.

Edit: The response I get is "12a9" with 2 odd ascii characters trailing it (a question mark symbol and a white circle with black border.

Comment: What's the problem? What error did you get, if any?

Comment: [Whats this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064505/requesting-html-over-https-with-c-sharp-webclient)? I remember having to do something like this a long time back. Defo something to do with SSL so could be worth a shot

Comment: it's returning plain `XML`. whats wrong?

Comment: Hi musefan, I saw that post and that didn't really apply. The site seems to be using TLS/1.2

Comment: Hi Amit, if you view the URL in a browser, you get the XML. If you put the URL into webClient.DownloadString, you get a symbol character (which I assume refers to a redirect or tunnel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the headers in Fiddler, the response is GZip-encoded (compressed). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567313/uncompressing-gzip-response-from-webclient) for how to deal with this, since there's no "quick and easy" way with the `WebClient` class.

Comment: Such an easy answer. Works. Thanks so much! ^_^