# System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I am using the below code to send push notifications from my WCF web service

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Key=" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["apiKey"]);
    var nameValues = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"registration_id", objSendNotificationBE.RegistrationID},
        {"collapse_key", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
        {"data.payload", objSendNotificationBE.Message}
    };
    var resp = wc.UploadValues("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", nameValues);
    respMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);
    if (respMessage == "Error=InvalidRegistration")
    {
        string respMessage = "";
    }
}
```

It's working fine but sometimes I am getting the exception

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, NameValueCollection data)
```

I have deployed my web service on azure server.

Comment: Can you properly format your code? It is hard to read at the moment

Comment: try to add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; before using (var wc = new WebClient())

Comment: Dear  Jitender thanx for the reply but as i mentioned that this issue is coming some time not regularly, how do i check why its happening only some time not for all request.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a request to a site that uses SSL/TLS i.e. starts with https. Like you alluded to in your comment, you need to configure your web client to use SSL/TLS. You need to figure out whether the remote server you are trying to reach uses SSL or TLS then use the correct security mode.

You can see this answered in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064505/requesting-html-over-https-with-c-sharp-webclient)

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri address = new Uri("https://archive.org/details/OTRR_In_The_Name_Of_The_Law_Singles");

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 ;

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var stream = webClient.OpenRead(address);
            using (StreamReader sr =new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var page = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Certificate validation callback.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
        if (error == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate [{0}] Policy Error: '{1}'",
            cert.Subject,
            error.ToString());

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I resolve this issue by adding these two lines ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;   But i am not getting why this error coming for some time not for every time we call the web services.