# Get HTML from URL - StreamReader uses another character encoding?

Tags: c#, utf-8, streamreader

I want to get the HTML from this URL: https://store.steampowered.com/app/513710/SCUM/

This should be easy, but I couldn't do it due to an SSL/TLS error.

So I used code from this question: [Requesting html over https with c# Webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064505/requesting-html-over-https-with-c-sharp-webclient)

Finally I could fill my StreamReader, but when I try to use ReadToEnd() with a string, I get a corrupt string, something like this: "�"

This must be something about character encoding, but if you open: https://store.steampowered.com/app/513710/SCUM/

And then open your browser console, you can see at the beginning:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

While at the provided code:

```
webClient.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
```

You have utf-8, so I just have no idea why I'm having this problem. I tried to replace:

```
StreamReader(webClient.OpenRead(steamURL));
```

With:

```
StreamReader(webClient.OpenRead(steamURL), Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

But it still didn't get the proper text. I tried to add all the information I could, if you need anything else I'll edit the question.

Thank you for your time and have a nice day.

Regards,

David

PS: This is my code right now:

```
private StreamReader getStreamReader(string steamURL, WebClient webClient)
{
    return new StreamReader(webClient.OpenRead(steamURL), Encoding.UTF8, true);
}

private void getSteamCosts()
{
    // When I try to access an Steam HTML, SSL error appears
    // We need an specific security protocol
    // I check all, just in case
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
            delegate
        {
            return true;
        });
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;"
            + " U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625"
            + " Firefox/3.6.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
        webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+"
            + "xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        webClient.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
        webClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";
        webClient.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";

        StreamReader sr = null;

        string steamURL = "https://store.steampowered.com/app/513710/SCUM/";

        try
        {
            // This one should work
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            sr = getStreamReader(steamURL, webClient);
            lbFinalSteam.Text = "TLS12Final";
        }
        catch (Exception) // Bad coding practice, just wanted it to work
        {
            // If that's not the case, I try the rest
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                sr = getStreamReader(steamURL, webClient);
                lbFinalSteam.Text = "TLSFinal";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                    sr = getStreamReader(steamURL, webClient);
                    lbFinalSteam.Text = "SSL3Final";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
                            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
                        sr = getStreamReader(steamURL, webClient);
                        lbFinalSteam.Text = "TLS11Final";
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        lbFinalSteam.Text = "NoFinal";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (sr != null)
        {
            string allLines = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

edit: maybe the problem is how I transform the StreamReader into a string? I mean this line:

```
string allLines = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Should I use anything else?

Comment: It's not a character encoding issue, the response from that URL is Gzip compressed & your not decompressing it. See this to enable automatic decompression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata  or remove your Accept-Encoding header and see if the server stops using Gzip as it should.

Comment: Oh my, it works!! I love you. :D

Answer (score 1):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k already wrote, the problem wasn't the encoding but I was getting a compressed Gzimp. I just removed this:

```
webClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";
```

And it works! Thank you Alex K! :D