# C# WebClient Https GET request 3x slower than other sites

Tags: c#, google-maps, https, webclient

I cannot use google api for this project, but need to make a simple google query, I do this by using ssl3 and tls12 on WebClient, setting the header manually (am not sure if this helps) and simply sending a GET request, for some reason, this takes *10 seconds*, but one to StackOverflow takes a mere 3 seconds. Yet when using chrome both load instantly, what is the bottleneck on using WebClient? How can I get SSL GET requests as fast as chrome does?

Second question: If the page contains JS, how can one execute the js on the "document" retrieved *without* using a web browser and *rendering the whole thing*

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: removing the header modifying code speeds it up, but google is still incredibly slow, I'm presuming they do this intentionally? Is there any way around this?

```
//in main
  WebCrawler wc = new WebCrawler();
            string page = wc.load("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064505/requesting-html-over-https-with-c-sharp-webclient");
            page = wc.load("https://www.google.com/maps?q=computer+shops+near+me&rlz=1C1GCEA_enZA855ZA855&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1lY-c4eDjAhUtWhUIHf8DDKUQ_AUIEigB");

...
// webcrawler class
WebClient webClient;
        public WebCrawler()
        {

            webClient = new WebClient();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;



        }
        public  string load(string uri)
        {
            Uri address = new Uri(uri);

            {
                webClient.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36");
                webClient.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "https://www.google.com/");
             //    webClient.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,
                var stream = webClient.OpenRead(address);
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var page = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return page;
                }
            }
        }
        private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
        {
            if (error == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate [{0}] Policy Error: '{1}'",
                cert.Subject,
                error.ToString());

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use WebClient. Instead, you may use `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest` and set `AutomaticDecompression` to `GZip, Deflate`.

When you set `AutomaticDecompression` to `GZip, deflate` using the following line (where `req` is `HttpWebRequest` for example):

```cs
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

An HTTP header called `Accept-Encoding` will be sent to the server with the value `GZip, Deflate` that asks the server to download the content in a compressed format.
Which means, a smaller size content to be downloaded and also a lower time required.
The `HttpWebRequest` will take care of decompressing the data sent from the server.

Same concept I explained on `HttpWebRequest` can be applied to `HttpClient`

Comment: Does this support https?

Comment: @BinkyNichols, yes. You can use `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient` and set `AutomaticDecompression` with https requests.

Comment: Doesn't improve time at all,

Issue is, when I load same page in a WebBrowser Control, it's about 1 second, yet 10 seconds in pure GET request.

Comment: Were you able to get this sped up? I implemented the following two settings:
`ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;`
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
and my webclient speed dropped a couple of seconds from what it was. But I have to declare TLS1.2 or else it attempts to use something else and the web request fails.