# 403 Forbidden error while invoking API in C# code

Tags: c#, client, access-token

This API is working through postman.
I am trying the same third-party API from my application like below:

```
    string requestUrl = string.Empty;
    string result = string.Empty;
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    using (client)
    {
        requestUrl = "https://api.fyndx1.de/hogwarts/aggregators/api/v1/config1/authToken";
        client.QueryString.Add("username", "tester");
        client.QueryString.Add("password", "pwd123");
        result = client.DownloadString(requestUrl);
    }
```

403 error is coming. I tried to add User agent to header parameters after querystring but no use.

```
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may have missed to pass the API access key or token via another Http Header - check again.

Comment: This is the api call to get the token.

Comment: Then apart from the username and password in Query string, that API is expecting some other Header or a query string value that you are not sending, hence it is returning you the 403.

Comment: Then how is it working in postman. Am i missing something?

Comment: Is that webserver using TLS 1.2 or SSL3, how is postman configured? check that. Based on that, this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097642/14973743) may be tried, to use Ssl3 if your server not handling TLS 1.2 or vice versa.

Comment: For .NET 4.5 or later, use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: After adding this line also, same 403 error. I have added all the request headers from postman also but no progress.

Comment: There is nothing else I can suggest, just ensure any `SSL certificate config` done in `postman` are also available to your code too, and all the required HTTP `headers` and query `params` are being sent. Other than this, no reason for 403 error. BTW, why are u not using `HttpClient` instead?