# Does .Net Framework 4.8 support SNI?

Tags: tls1.2, client-certificates, sni, .net-4.8

I'm making an HTTPS call over TLS 1.2 with client certificates to another company using .Net Framework 4.8 and the handshake fails after the client certificate is sent.  Their company support claims .Net framework does not support SNI using this page as reference https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/what-is-sni-technology/.  However my network capture indicates it does, since it includes the "server_name" extension in the client hello.[.Net framework call with SNI extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP9Aj.png)  The same call can be made successfully using python so there is evidence they are correct, but I can't find any definitive answer online regarding .Net Framework.  How can we determine if the issue is their network or lack of support in our framework?

Edit: This website indicates there is support since 4.5 https://developer.awhere.com/api/server-name-indication-sni-support-requirements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971236/server-name-indication-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Framework don't care about SNI support, because .NET has no knowledge of it. Network operations in .NET Framewrok are built around a network stack and low-level API provided by operating system. If you were able to install .NET 4.8, then you are running your app on a modern client that certainly supports SNI. This means that the issue is elsewhere, but not in .NET Framework.

> I can't find any definitive answer online regarding .Net Framework

and you won't find for reasons explained above.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, it does NOT, not in NetStandard 2.0 either.
But it does with netcore-5+.

Prior to that, while it supported client connections, it did not support customized selecting of the TLS-certificate based on SNI prior to netcore-5.

You could do it prior to that with the StreamsExtended library, though. 
However, that's not part of the official .NET Framework, but a 3rd party library. 
So no, the full .NET framework does not support that at all.